# TDM medium access control

Tags: network, layer1

In a TDM medium access control bus LAN, suppose the channel has a effective bandwidth of 10Mbps and each station has effective throughput of 1Mbps, then what is the maximum number of stations allowed ?

---

Here the answer is 10/1 = 10. I don't understand the term "maximum number of stations allowed" in TDM.

If we are dividing both the bandwidths then it means that we are considering the possibility of all stations transmitting together and hence we are saying only 10 stations can transmit at a time.

But in TDM, only one station is allowed to transmit data at a time right ? So how does dividing the bandwidths make sense here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the given time period of 1 second, each host will transmit. The circuit will have transmitted up to 10 Mb, and each host will have transmitted up to 1 Mb in that second. That means you can have a maximum number of 10 hosts on the circuit.

TDM will divide the full circuit into a number of virtual circuits, and a host has exclusive use of a virtual circuit. If the circuit is 10 Mbps and the virtual circuits are each 1 Mbps, then you can only have 10 hosts using the circuit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please tell me the difference between effective bandwidth of **channel** and effective bandwidth of each **station** ? I am slightly confused between these terms.

Comment: The channel is the full circuit in the context of the question. What the question is saying is that the circuit is 10 Mbps, and each virtual circuit is 1 Mbps. The circuit will transmit each virtual circuit for 1/10 of a second.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But in general can you tell me the difference between both these terms ?

Comment: That really depends on the context. For example, in the context of cabling, a channel is the end-to-end cable, including the patch cables and horizontal cable. Looking at this question, you must figure that the channel is the full circuit, and the effective throughput of a host is the virtual circuit speed of the host. Each host will have one virtual circuit, and it has exclusive use of the virtual circuit. If you calculate the number of virtual circuits, then you know the maximum number of hosts.

Comment: Actually I am coming across these terms in many questions(like aloha,csma/CD). Although I am getting the right answer but I am not able to understand the exact difference between these terms. In general I know that effective bandwidth means amount of useful data that is actually being transferred. So we usually multiply the raw bandwidth with the efficiency to get the effective bandwidth or throughput.

Comment: That is normally how I would view throughput, but clearly the author meant effective bandwidth, not how I see throughput. It is probably because the question is only about the raw bits on the wire, not any protocols above OSI layer-1. Another book may use different terms.

Comment: Just want to clarify one thing. So here if one time slot = 1/10 = 0.1sec . Then each station will transmit 1Mb in 0.1 sec in that given time slot right ? So at the end of 1 sec, all 10 stations would have transmitted 1Mb.

Comment: Yes, that is what it means. Effectively, each host can transmit 1 Mbps, even though it is done in bursts. TDM circuits have burst rate, but that is getting ahead.